# in R,Is unset environmental variables makes permanent unset

Tags: r

in R, I would like to "unset" environmental variable's, but If i re-run,R script are the environmental variables get set back or resetting forever. please let me know.

Comment: If you are referring to `Sys.unsetenv`, values are set/unset for the current R session only. The values will depend on what's defined in your code and how you run it (_e.g._ from command line, in an RStudio session).